# How to transform accented characters in html using Javascript?

Tags: html, javascript

I'm using a form to record data in my database using AJAX. So, how this works? I get the form data via Javascript, request a URL which is written in PHP then insert to the database.

The problem is that I'm using Latin 1 characters so the form is expecting also accented characters like **ó**. I need to convert this **ó** to html (`&oacute;`) in javascript, so that I can pass it to PHP.

How doI do that?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989039/javascript-replacing-html-char-code-with-actual-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to make an AJAX request to a PHP page outputting the result of `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
function escapeHTMLEncode(str) {
  var div = document.createElement(‘div’);
  var text = document.createTextNode(str);
  div.appendChild(text);
  return div.innerHTML;
 }
```

http://sanzon.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/neat-little-html-encoding-trick-in-javascript/