# Calling function in HTML, from external .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to call a function I've declared in my .js file, in my HTML document.

js/newsalerts.js

```
function unescapeHTML(html) {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989105/4650297
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    return ("innerText" in div) ? div.innerText : div.textContent; // IE | FF
}
```

index.html (using Flask)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/newsalerts.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        queries = "{{ search_terms }}";
        console.log(unescapeHTML(queries));
    </script>
    ...
```

I'm trying to get the `unescapeHTML` function to run on my `queries`variable, but keep getting the error that

> unescapeHTML is not defined

I've also tried `console.log(newsalerts.unescapeHTML(queries))`, same error.

Comment: Check your network console and make sure it is finding and loading the expected js file.

Comment: When your page renders, right click and select "view page source" - does the script that should load newsalerts.js look right? Open the network panel in your browser's developer tools, is newsalerts.js loading correctly?

You almost certainly have either an error where your script URL is not correct or the file isn't actually being loaded from your server.

Comment: Is the newsalerts.js located in the 'static/js' folder?

Comment: Probably the script above is not loaded for some reason (wrong url, config path etc). Apart from this, you don't need flask to preprocess that, try this: https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/taskq

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut - Yeah, it loads the javascript I expect it to.  In the Network panel, everything loads (status 200). (Newsalerts.js is "GET" method, is that correct?)  EDIT: I deleted the post. I got it working, but didn't change anything -- so, can't reproduce. Thanks for your tips though, I learned about the network panel :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (?) the solution to this was not a programming one.  Thanks to the folks commenting on my OP, I was able to confirm that my `.js` file was indeed loading correctly, and the code was correct.

...except looking through the code, my `unescapeHTML` function was missing -- but it was in my .js file!

The problem was when I restarted the Flask server, and refreshed my browser, it must have kept the `js` file from the cache.  Once I did a hard refresh, the full correct js file loaded and it works as expected.

So, don't forget to "hard refresh" the page if you change any of the underlying code.